# path error Json encode array mysql

Tags: android, json

i want to parse json array in android from [link](http://nikhil.webhorizons.in)

my database table has values

```
(5, 'Hotel Happy Times', 'Hotel Happy Times Nashik (formerly known as Was sans Inn) located next to Kalika Mandir at Gadkari Chowk is one of the best in the vicinity. Happy Times is an awesome threesome of amazing food, excellent ambience and great hospitality. T', '12', **'http://www.nikhil.webhorizons.com/img/img5.png'**)
```

last value is image link that i want parse but after json array encode it will not print correct path as i expected.

it will gives array values like this

```
{"placeid":"0",

"placename":"KEBAB",

"placedescription":"Nashik is a mysterious blend of different cultures... \t",

"distance":"1",

"image":"**http:\/\/www.nikhil.webhorizons.com/\img/\img1.png**"

}

]

}
```

You can check this [here](http://nikhil.webhorizons.in)

Comment: Some body edit this question. What a messy topic you have @Sidharth Joy?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove backslashes from string when you parse JSON with [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
String url = url.replace("\\", "");
```